# CSS - Background-size: cover; is too big. How can i re-size?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying a simple CSS parallex affect by fixing the background-image with a background-size of cover. Everything seems to work as i'd like but the background-image is too big. It's also cropped and enlarged compared to the original file. If i try to remove the "cover" attribute, and replace it with a more specific size the "parallex" type affect goes away, and i'm left with an odd scrolling transition with the image.

What's the best way to re-size the background-image so i can crop it the way i'd like but also have the affect i desire? As of now the image is too zoomed in.

```
    .fullwidth_100 {
width:100%;
height:500px;
background-image:url('http://www.myorderdesk.com/Providers/206190/Files/31/full_width_image_1.jpg');
background-position: center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/*background-size: 100% 80%; */
background-size:cover;
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-moz-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-ms-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-o-transition: background-image 0.4s;
transition: background-image 0.4s;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Here is my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/b3e4btbe/3/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download your image
Step 2: find Image width and height 
Step 3: set the height and width like so:

```
.fullwidth_100 {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 500px;
}`
```

```css
.fullwidth_100 {
width: 1440px;
height: 500px;
background-image:url('http://www.myorderdesk.com/Providers/206190/Files/31/full_width_image_1.jpg');
background-position: center center;
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-moz-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-ms-transition: background-image 0.4s;
-o-transition: background-image 0.4s;
transition: background-image 0.4s;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth_100">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <h3>Convenience is our goal</h3>
            <p>With 30 years of experience we are your #1 choice in <br>providing quality printing solutions.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more about us ></a>
            </div>
 </div>
 
 <br>
 <p>
  Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. 
 </p>
 
 <p>
  Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. 
 </p>
 
 <p>
  Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. 
 </p>
 
 <p>
  Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. 
 </p>
 
 <p>
  Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. Content Goes Here. 
 </p>
```

Comment: @StinkyTofu yeah will do when I'm home!

Comment: @StinkyTofu Click the run code snippet below the code